# How to get more accurate 'Read' stats in Google Reader

Tags: google-reader

Google Reader provides stats on the % Read for each feed. The problem is that most of these(for me at least) are at 100% so are not very useful.

I use the 'j' shortcut key to flick through the unread items but this automatically marks the item as read even if I didn't actually read it.

How do I mark an item as 'not new' so that the stats provide an accurate view of my feed reading habits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for an "ignore this post" feature. This does not exist so far.

I personally use n/p instead of j/k and mark all posts that I am not going to read again as "read" - no matter if I actually read them or if I just want to ignore them.

Things to read later are kept unread and/or starred. It's rather easy to organize Google Reader like this.

However, I agree that it may be difficult to measure which feeds consist of mostly uninteresting (thus "ignored") posts. You may try to use the "Like" feature instead, but this is a rather crude workaround.

Comment: Spot on. I use Google Reader in the same way you do and have asked the question because I want to know which feeds are just a waste of my time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `n` (next) and `p` (previous) shortcuts instead of `j`/`k` to **select the next item in the list view without opening it**.

Comment: the problem with n and p is that they don't remove the items from your Reader unread items. And in expanded view, they work the same as j and k.