# Can you specify how posts in Google Reader are marked as read?

Tags: google-reader

Google Reader tends in my opinion to be a bit over-eager to mark posts as read - if you click on a post or scroll over the top of it it will be marked as read.

Is there a setting to control the conditions for a post being marked as read?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get more accurate 'Read' stats in Google Reader](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/664/how-to-get-more-accurate-read-stats-in-google-reader)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I can go to Google reader settings->Preferences and uncheck `In expanded view, mark items as read when you scroll past them.` That makes it slightly less eager.

Answer (score 4):

If you use list view instead of expanded view, posts won't be marked as read until you click to open them.