# Is there a way to scroll news in Google Reader without marking it read?

Tags: google-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get more accurate ‘Read’ stats in Google Reader](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/664/how-to-get-more-accurate-read-stats-in-google-reader)

When you scroll through a feed in Google Reader it marks everything you look at as read and but if I am just browsing real quick and want to keep them as unread, then I have to click each one "keep unread".

**Is there a way to e.g. with CTRL-scroll to read through the feeds without marking them as "read"?**

Comment: Dupe http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/664/how-to-get-more-accurate-read-stats-in-google-reader

Answer (score 7):

In Settings, there is an option called 'In expanded view, mark items as read when you scroll past them.' under 'Scroll Tracking'. Unchecking that will prevent items from being marked as read when you are scrolling. The downside is that you now have to mark each one as read.

Comment: Or you use the "Mark all as read" button, if you've read them all.

Answer (score 1):

In Settings, under Scroll Tracking, uncheck "In expanded view, mark items as read when you scroll past them." Does this work for you?